# HTTP Basic Authentication in Java with Proxy

Tags: java, http, proxy, http-headers, basic-authentication

I'm trying to use HTTP post to send a file to a web server that requires basic authentication.

My workplace has recently implemented a change to the proxy server and it now also requires basic authentication.

How can I enter my credentials for both of these servers in a single HttpPost request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I needed to add a "Proxy-Authorization" header as well.

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://host:port/test/login");

String encoding = Base64Encoder.encode ("your_user:your_password");
httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);

String proxyEncoding = Base64Encoder.encode ("proxy_user:proxy_password");
httpPost.setHeader("Proxy-Authorization", "Basic " + proxyEncoding);

System.out.println("executing request " + httpPost.getRequestLine());
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add in your http header following line, as described in [basic authorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication):

1. The username and password are combined with a single colon.
2. The resulting string is encoded using the RFC2045-MIME variant of
   Base64, except not limited to 76 char/line.
3. The authorization method and a space i.e. "Basic " is then put before the encoded string.

---

Look at example with Apache HttpClient:

```
String encoding = Base64Encoder.encode ("your_login:your_password");
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://host:post/test/login");
httppost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);

System.out.println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

Comment: So the login and password are for the web server. What about the username and password of the proxy server?